# Can Keycloak provide SSO via Apache web service?

Tags: apache-2.4, single-sign-on, alfresco

I'm trying to use Keycloak as an external authentication service for Alfresco (see: Can Keycloak be used as external (SSO) authentication service for Alfresco and Share?).

I've gotten no responses to my original post, so I'm looking for other ways to skin this cat. Perhaps I could install an Apache web server in front of Alfresco (Tomcat) and use that for remote authentication/SSO. Does anyone know if that is possible (with Keycloak)? Does anyone have any other ideas? We'd like to use Alfresco in conjunction with our (Java EE) application.

Someone on StackOverflow suggested that I move this question here, but there isn't even a keycloak tag available.

Edit: This question deals with using Keycloak with **Apache web server** to provide external (SSO) authentication service for Alfresco and Share.

Comment: Since you've not received any hits on your original question, and since I've not even heard of this product before now, it's quite likely that you will get much better answers from a product-specific venue.

Comment: [keycloak](http://keycloak.jboss.org/) has a [mailing list](https://lists.jboss.org/mailman/listinfo/keycloak-user) which is getting dozens of posts monthly